# Python optparse not working for me

Tags: python, optparse

I'm currently learning on how to use the Python optparse module. I'm trying the following example script but the args variable comes out empty. I tried this using Python 2.5 and 2.6 but to no avail.

```
import optparse

def main():
  p = optparse.OptionParser()
  p.add_option('--person', '-p', action='store', dest='person', default='Me')
  options, args = p.parse_args()

  print '\n[Debug]: Print options:', options
  print '\n[Debug]: Print args:', args
  print

  if len(args) != 1:
    p.print_help()
  else:
    print 'Hello %s' % options.person

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Output:

```
>C:\Scripts\example>hello.py -p Kelvin

[Debug]: Print options: {'person': 'Kelvin'}

[Debug]: Print args: []

Usage: hello.py [options]
```

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p PERSON, --person=PERSON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `args` variable holds any arguments that *were not assigned to an option*.  Your code is indeed working properly by assigning `Kelvin` to the `person` option variable.

If you tried running `hello.py -p Kelvin file1.txt`, you would find that `person` still was assigned the value `"Kelvin"`, and then your `args` would contain `"file1.txt"`.

See also [the documentation on `optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#tutorial):

> `parse_args()`  returns two values:
>
> - `options`, an object containing values for all of your options—e.g. if `--file` takes a single string argument, then `options.file` will be the filename supplied by the user, or `None` if the user did not supply that option
> - `args`, the list of positional arguments leftover after parsing options

Comment: Oh, I see. I read help docs but I guess I have to read carefully to fully understand. Thanks! Wow, first time here and I get a quick response.

Comment: You should select an an answer, so that people know you are trustworthy and you'll get a fast response next time too!

Answer (score 1):

According to `optparse` help:

"On success returns a pair (values, args) where 'values' is an Values instance (with all your option values) and 'args' is the list of arguments **left over** after parsing options."

Try `hello.py -p Kelving abcd` - 'Kelvin' will be parsed by optparse, 'abcd' will land in `args` variable returned by `parse_args`

Answer (score 0):

Note: "options" is a dictionary with the options you added. "Args" is a list with the unparsed arguments. You should not be looking at length "args". Here is a transcript to illustrate:

```
moshez-mb:profile administrator$ cat foo
import optparse

def main():
    p = optparse.OptionParser()
    p.add_option('--person', '-p', action='store', dest='person', default='Me')
    options, args = p.parse_args()
    print '\n[Debug]: Print options:', options
    print '\n[Debug]: Print args:', args
    print
    if len(args) != 1:
        p.print_help()
    else:
        print 'Hello %s' % options.person

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
moshez-mb:profile administrator$ python foo

[Debug]: Print options: {'person': 'Me'}

[Debug]: Print args: []

Usage: foo [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p PERSON, --person=PERSON
moshez-mb:profile administrator$ python foo -p Moshe

[Debug]: Print options: {'person': 'Moshe'}

[Debug]: Print args: []

Usage: foo [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p PERSON, --person=PERSON
moshez-mb:profile administrator$ python foo -p Moshe argument

[Debug]: Print options: {'person': 'Moshe'}

[Debug]: Print args: ['argument']

Hello Moshe
moshez-mb:profile administrator$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
noargs = ast.literal_eval(options.__str__()).keys()
if len(noargs) != 1:
    parser.error("ERROR: INCORRECT NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the ast module has anything to do with why the args variable is empty. The number of arguments is not correct, they are just assigned differently.

Comment: could you please let me know what is wrong with the code.btw this is a work around...i could not make len(args) to make it work ....not sure if i am missing some thing.

Comment: It does not address the question, the poster was asking why `args` was empty. The answer was that args **should** be empty, because that is how the `optparser` works. Your code will add the `'person'` key and display it, but that is not what is supposed to happen here.